# Azure cli - wait for operation to complete before next statement executes

Tags: azure-cli

How do I make my cli script wait until a resource is provisioned before attempting the next operation?

For example I am creating a waf policy and then attempting to assign that waf policy to an app gateway

The issue is that the waf policy is still being created

```
    # WAF Policy
    az network application-gateway waf-policy create \
        --name $wafPolicyName 
        --resource-group $resourceGroupName
    
    # App Gateway - wont allow to create without a private IP
    az network application-gateway create \
        --name  $appGatewayName \
        --resource-group $resourceGroupName \
        --waf-policy $wafPolicyName
```

This result is an error:- Another operation on this or dependent resource is in progress

How do I make it wait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this: `az network application-gateway waf-policy wait --name $wafPolicyName --resource-group $resourceGroupName --created`

Here is a link about how to use [az network application-gateway waf-policy wait](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/application-gateway/waf-policy?view=azure-cli-latest#az_network_application_gateway_waf_policy_wait).

The `wait` command works perfectly on my side:
[image]